# C++ error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const char*’

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation

I'm using a function to download a file.

```
void downloadFile(const char* url, const char* fname) {
  //..
}
```

This is called like :

```
downloadFile("http://servera.com/file.txt", "/user/tmp/file.txt");
```

This working fine.

But I want to change the URL to be a value from an array. The array stores encrypted values which when decrypted are strings, so I get the issue `error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const char*’`

I've tried:

```
 string test = decode(foo[5]);
 const char* t1= test.c_str();
 downloadFile(t1 "filename.txt", "/user/tmp/file.txt");

downloadFile(t1 + "filename.txt", "/user/tmp/file.txt");
```

and

```
downloadFile((decode(foo[5]).c_str()) + "filename.txt", "/user/tmp/file.txt");
```

which gives:
`error: invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char [17]’ to binary ‘operator+’`

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to add pointers (which obviously isn't what you want to do). You should construct the whole path in a `std::string` variable first, and then pass `c_str()` to the `downloadFile()` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C-strings can't be concatenated with `+`.

Use `std::string::+` instead:

```
downloadFile((test + "filename.txt").c_str(), "/user/tmp/file.txt");
```

Note that `c_str` only returns a pointer to the `std::string`'s internal character array, so it's valid only during the execution of the `downloadFile` function.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
downloadFile((decode(foo[5]) + "filename.txt").c_str(), "/user/tmp/file.txt");
```

The operator+ is not defined for char arrays.

Comment: Thanks I've found this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your code is that you are trying to use `operator+` to concatenate raw **C strings** (i.e. raw `const char*` pointers, or raw `char []` arrays), which doesn't work.

In C, you should use proper library functions (like `strncat` or safer variants) to do that; but since you are using **C++**, you can do better, and write *easier* code: just use a **C++ string class**, like `std::string`.

In fact, the C++ standard library offers convenient overloads for `operator+` that work with `std::string`, so you can concatenate C++ strings in an easy, intuitive and safe way; for example:

```
// Build your URL string
std::string test = decode(foo[5]);
std::string url = test + "filename.txt";

// Use std::string::c_str() to convert from C++ string
// to C raw string pointer const char*
downloadFile(url.c_str(), "/user/tmp/file.txt");
```